# getting SLF4J error when starting corda network

Tags: corda

i am getting SLF4J error while booting up corda netowrk, 
I am using JDK8_221, corda 4.1, windows OS, 
I am using gradle
Logs:

> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
>   SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J:
>   See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further
>   detail s.

tried same with JDK8_181, JDK8_191
Env. variable and path variable are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue could be due to the version of SLF4J.

Use 1.6 or 1.7 version of SLF4J.

Go through the following link for details

URL: https://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.html

Excerpts from the above link -

> ```
> As of SLF4J version 1.8.0, the static binder mechanism (StaticLoggerBinder) is deprecated.
>
> This class exists for backward compatibility earlier versions of slf4j-api.jar, in particular in the 1.6.x and the 1.7.x series.
>
> Note that this class is likely to be removed in future releases of SLF4J.
> ```

Comment: I am using 1.7.28 as well as tried 1.6.1, still same issue, its making corda build to fails.